# Bring one series in order of another series based on values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series which contain the same elements but in a different order. I want to bring the second series in the same order as the first series based on the values in the first series and then get the indices of that second series after it was reordered. How can I do that?

**Example:**

Bring `bar` in the same order as `foo` based on the values in `foo` and return the rearranged indices.

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Series(['d','b','c','a'])
bar = pd.Series(['c','a','b','d'])
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that it's *possible* to reorder `bar` into `foo`?

Comment: `pd.Series(bar.index, index=bar).reindex(foo)` ..?

Comment: Are your series always going to be the same length and contain the same values? What is the desired behavior if bar contains values that are not in foo?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could "swap" your `bar` series values with it's index, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with the values from `foo`:

```
pd.Series(bar.index, index=bar).reindex(foo)
```

[out]

```
d    3
b    2
c    0
a    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if `foo` and `bar` have duplicate elements?

Comment: OP hasn't specified

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to sort foo identically the same as bar then return the index of foo.

You can use pd.CategoricalDtype to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Series(['d','b','c','a'])
bar = pd.Series(['c','a','b','d'])

bar_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(bar.unique(), ordered=True)

new_foo = foo.astype(bar_type).sort_values()
print(new_foo)
```

Output:

```
2    c
3    a
1    b
0    d
dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [c < a < b < d]
```

Get index:

```
index_new_foo=new_foo.index
index_new_foo
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([2, 3, 1, 0], dtype='int64')
```

---

In case, I did this backward:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.Series(['d','b','c','a'])
bar = pd.Series(['c','a','b','d'])

foo_type= pd.CategoricalDtype(foo.unique(), ordered=True)
new_bar = bar.astype(foo_type).sort_values()
new_bar.index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([3, 2, 0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Or did I do that backward?  Did you want bar to be the same order as foo or foo the same order as bar?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`searchsorted`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+searchsorted&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+searc&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i59j0l4.2359j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
a = np.argsort(bar)
a[np.searchsorted(bar[a], foo)].values #.to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is simply to use `df.join` with a `reset_index` and a `set_index`:

```
foo1 = foo.reset_index().set_index(0)
bar1 = bar.reset_index()
bar1.columns = ['index2',0] #this is so column names don't overlap
foo2 = foo1.join(bar1.set_index(0)).sort_index()
```

This gives you the values as index, then one column per dataframe giving matching index:

```
   index  index2
0               
a      3       1
b      1       2
c      2       0
d      0       3
```